# Table in MySQL to show product data in Magento 2 after reindexing process

Tags: magento2, database, reindex, indexing

I want to know about those MYSQL tables which is used to fetch data for Front-end Products in Magento 2 after re-indexing process.

Like which table will be used after re-indexing process to show products on store.
And i want also know which table will be responsible for particular reindex process.

And if any post that is explain about reindexing process it will be very helpfull.

Any help is appriciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When there are any changes in the object of a database that the Magento 2 system has indexes for, a new trigger appears in the table with the _cl postfix if there is such a table. If there is no such table, a new one is generated. The mview.xml files are responsible for defining the data which changes will be tracked in the _cl (change log) table.
For example, Magento/Catalog/etc/mview.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Mview/etc/mview.xsd">
…
<view id="catalog_category_product" class="Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Category\Product" group="indexer">
   <subscriptions>
       <table name="catalog_category_entity" entity_column="entity_id" />
       <table name="catalog_category_entity_int" entity_column="entity_id" />
   </subscriptions>
</view>
…
</config>
```

From this extract, you can see that the **catalog_category_product_cl** will be created. It will contain the information about the changes in **catalog_category_entity** and **catalog_category_entity_int** tables

All the change log tables are created by a certain INDEXER_TABLE_NAME + ‘_cl’ rule.The tables contain the **version_id** columns as autoincrement and entity_id that contains the object identifier that needs to be reindexed.

you can read further from [Magento Docx.](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/indexing.html)

Comment: Thanks for your response. For catalog_category_product_cl table what is entity_id in lamen lang. will you plz tell me. @hafiz

Comment: and one more thing for updating catalog_category_product index only two table is working firstly data goes in catalog_category_product_index_tmp table then in catalog_category_product_index_store1_replica for 1 store site am i correct .

Comment: @Prits entity_id id object identifier. for example in catalog_category_product_cl table if entity_id is 5 then its mean category id = 5 need to be reindexing.

yes you are right data is store accordingly to their store(catalog_category_product_index_storenumber_replica).

Comment: Thanks for your response so it means for one store for catalog_category_product indexer  catalog_category_product_index_store1_replica is the final table for that index.